# The Important Difference: Overloading vs. Specialization

Tags: c++

HI friends , Any one help me

1. The Important Difference: Overloading vs. Specialization in C++

It's important to make sure we have the terms with proof .Thanks in advance

The doubt arised  "Why Not Specialize Function Templates?"

Comment: Why don't you start with your thoughts as to an answer, and put it in your question.  Also, what type of proof are you looking for, since a mathematical proof won't work.

Comment: @InSane: [Using the `possible-homework` tag is discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ Something to get you started

Comment: Exactly. What do you mean with proof? And really it depends who you ask. There are good and bad things to say for both. Usually if you're writing a library that will be used by third parties, it is better to specialize for clarity 's sake. And again. No proof except oppinions.

Comment: I swear I've seen this *exact* wording before. Ah, there it is: these are the exact words taken from GoTW #17: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the article [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) by Herb Sutter.

Comment: A link to the relevant GotW would be sufficient, no?

Comment: ... and perhaps a detailed citation.

Comment: @Alex B:Earlier i  pasted the link.But for that user the link is not opening ..thats why ..i try to paste the content.

Comment: This text is copyright Herb Sutter. Posting to Stack Overflow implies a creative commons license, and you *cannot* grant that license unless you're the copyright holder. If that's you, Mr. Sutter, then I'm sorry to bother you, please ignore me. Otherwise, I don't think this is fair use and I don't think it's appropriate to copy other people's work wholesale to SO (even with attribution), where it will be labelled with a license that SO is not authorised to grant.

Comment: @BE Student: I had to do a double-take. If you're going to post someone else's article verbatim, be *very clear*. I added an attribution besides the link… probably I should delete the content, but I'll flag instead so the moderator can decide if it's a copyright violation.

Comment: As a grad student, you should be VERY aware of this kind of thing.

Comment: @Potatoswatter,@Steve Jessop ,@ALex B:Earlier i pasted the link.But for that user the link is not opening ..thats why ..i try to paste the content.i already said why i pasted.I don't know that Pasting  is a not a good job ..i mean it leads to copyright violation.sorry for that

Answer (score 5):

Read [GoTW #17](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) for the very detailed answer.

Comment: Your answer was necessary and sufficient. +1 from me.

Comment: answer that simply contain a link are discouraged, usually a discussion / summary of the content of the page linked is expected... just in case your link suddenly points into the void, in which case your answer would become completely meaningless.